# How to sort numbers with leading zeros in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Hi I have String list as input with leading zeros and I am wondering how to sort them.

**Input(unsorted)**

```
0-2
0-1
1
1-2
1-0
1-1
4-3
```

**Output(sorted)**

```
0-1
0-2
1
1-0
1-1
1-2
4-3
```

I can remove "-" and leading zeroes but then `0-1 -> 1` and `1 -> 1` are the same and can not be sorted. Other thing that comes in my mind is to remove the zero and in these numbers that have not leading zero to put 0 behind so

```
0-1->1
1->10
10->100
```

then use Java sort and the back numbers in the start position but sorted?

**Edit:**

- Structure is unlimited in depth so 1-2-3-4-5-6...
- I can have only one leading 0
- Only dash(-) and point (.) are allowed decimeters.

Comment: Is it the case that you always have only one dash?  Or does the structure get more complex?

Comment: How many levels do you have? Max. 2? Unlimited?

Comment: What have you tried? - Did you check if the natural sort order of strings does what you need?

Comment: you can try override `equals` method of `Object`, assuming you create a new class.

Comment: A `Integer List` does not have leading Zeros, neither does it have dashes - what exact datatype are you working on?

Comment: Natural sort order of strings will not work if he has two digit numbers.

Comment: @redflar3 That won't get him anywhere.

Comment: How do you receive them ? A `List<String>`  ?

Comment: Clean way seems to be to create a class to hold the pairs of numbers (like (0,2),(0,1),(1,null) &c.) and have it implement `Comparable`.

Comment: @All I edited the question. Thanks for remarks.

Comment: what is issue in creating a `String[]` of all the values and then apply `Arrays.sort()`?

Comment: There is rather a question of possession. You just need to write a class container with a redefined method compare and getInt(). Numbers with a leading zero is always less than normal. More or less like this: http://pastebin.com/Rsy0AAfA

Comment: "Natural sort" probably does the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640280

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd split the string by the `-` character and then convert each part to an `int`:

```
public class StringPartsComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare (String s1, String s2) {
        String[] arr1 = s1.split("-");
        int len1 = arr1.length;

        String[] arr2 = s2.split("-");
        int len2 = arr2.length;

        int commonLength = Math.min(len1, len2);

        // Go over the "common" elements.
        // Return if any element differs from its counterpart
        for (int i = 0; i < commonLength; ++i) {
            int int1 = Integer.parseInt(arr1[i]);
            int int2 = Integer.parseInt(arr2[i]);
            int comp = Integer.compare(int1, int2);
            if (comp != 0) {
                return comp;
            }
        }

        // All the common elements are equal,
        // the longer string should be considered "bigger"
        return Integer.compare(len1, len2);
    }
}
```

Now, just use this custom comparator to sort your strings:

```
List<String> myList = ...;
Collections.sort(myList, new StringPartsComparator());
```

Comment: If the list is of `String` type then isn't the required output is in *natural order* ? Which can be directly sorted with `Collections.sort` without using custom comparator.

Comment: @TAsk if OP max number was 9 yes, (`"10" < "2"`)

Comment: @TAsk if we assume that the values between the separators are limited to single digits, I agree, the natural ordering should work just fine. The way I understood it, however, is that the elements between the separators represent numbers, so we'd like `"11-1"` come after `"2-0"`, so the natural ordering would be insufficient.